# Open Boostrap dynamic modal after AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have one page named test.html with one div named `id=display_modal_result` (to display content of modal) and another div named `id=item` (to display link for each modal).

In another page (modalcall.php) I have PHP script which generate multiple modal link and multiple modal content.

On test.html I call with AJAX script my PHP page and add the result in `#item` and `#display_modal_result`. But when I try to click on one link, the associate modal doesn't open.

An ideas?

Ajax script on test.html :

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "modalcall.php",
        success: function(data) {

          $('#item').html(data); // Add modal links
          $('#display_modal_result').html(data); // Add content modal
          $('#display_modal_result').on('click', '.item_link', function(){

          // Get ID of MODAL
          var targetmodal = $(this).attr('data-target');
          // Show modal 
          $(targetmodal).modal('show');
        });

        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
```

Html on test.html :

```
<div id="display_modal_menu">
<!-- Display X content modal from modalcall.php -->
</div>

<div id="item">
<!-- Display X modal link from modalcall.php -->
</div>
```

Script on modalcall.php :

```
// While to display X modal link
$result1 = mysql_query("select * from $mytable order by iditem");
while ($r1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) 
{
 $iditem= $r1['iditem'];
 $title= $r1['title'];

 echo '<div class="item_link">
       <div class="item_link_line" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal_'.$iditem.'" type="button">'.$title.'</div></div>';
}


// While to display each modal content
$result1 = mysql_query("select * from $mytable order by iditem");
while ($r1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) 
{
 $iditem= $r1['iditem'];
 $title= $r1['title'];
 $content= $r1['content'];
 echo '<div class="modal fade" id="#mymodal_'.$iditem.'" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel2" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="menumodal-container table-responsive">'.$title.'<br>'.$content.'<BR><BR>';
 echo '</div></div></div>';
}
```

Comment: What do you get if you log targetModal?

Comment: I have #mymodal_x displayed...that's the point. I don't know why it's no working :-\

Comment: Just to confirm, you're not seeing any errors in the console or anything? Just nothing happens. Is your jquery wrapped in document ready?

Comment: Yes no errors in the console, script loaded after document ready.